# How do I insert an API key header into Jersey resource request?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Using Jersey (Java):

```
Manager manager = client.resource(baseUrl + "/manager").header("Api-Key", apiKey).get(Manager.class);
```

What is wrong with the way I'm formatting my request? The developers say that the secret apiKey should be under "Api-Key". I get UnknownHostException when I try this (I know for a fact that my baseUrl/host is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the API-Key is a header value instead of a part of the URL string?

Test your URL strings with curl first to make sure things work as expected.  Many APIs look for something like this

```
curl www.test.com/manager?Api-Key=THE_API_KEY
```